# How do i resolve the problem Instance of fileName .env not found exception in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
Am currently storing my supabase API in an
```

.env file in my calendar app project but after debugging it produces Instance of 'FileNotFoundError' exception.
Please i need some help for i have being trying
to resolve this for quite some time.Thank you.

```
<!--this is my calendar class-->


import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:calendar_projects/config/constants.dart';

class CalPager extends StatelessWidget{
  static const String routeName='/CalPager';

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body:PageView(
        children:[
          'adventures-begin-mug@3x.png',
          'apple-and-juice@3x.png',
          'apples-on-tree@3x.png'
        ].map((e) => CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl:
          "${ReceivingID(env['SUPABASE_PROJECT_ID']!)}/$e",
          fit:BoxFit.cover,
          alignment:Alignment.center,
          placeholder: (context, url) =>
        const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget:(context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),))
          .toList(),));
  }
}


<!--this is my api-->
```

String ReceivingID(String
SUPABASE_ID)=>"https://$SUPABASE_ID.supabase.in/storage/v1/object/public/backgrounds";

//this is the .env file containing my api ID
SUPABASE_PROJECT_ID=afnijwzgndolyzotplkj

```
<!--main.dart-->


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:calendar_projects/app.dart';
void main()async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await load(fileName:" .env");

  runApp(const App());
}


<!--this is my gitignore-->


# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

.env
migrate_working_dir/



# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr

*.iws
.idea/
```

//And i do like to ask about a few useful cases of the .env except for storing api keys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add .env path to pubspec.yaml like

```
assets:
  - .env
```